# Android stock camera access

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that uses the camera however I'm currently using the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Which opens the camera but not the stock android camera app. Is there a way to do that? I want to use the stock camera so that I don't have to deal with saving photos/videos, or exception handling myself.

Comment: That's the correct intent. I'm assuming you have the other application set as your default camera app to handle the intent. Go to your list of installed apps.. find your other camera app, click "clear defaults" try again..

Comment: It says there is no default set. I don't have any other camera apps installed

Comment: If it's not opening the stock camera and you don't have another camera installed.. what app could it possibly be opening .....?

Comment: It's opening up the camera but it's not the same. It doesn't have the options to switch between panorama, video, and regular photo. And it doesn't save the photo that you capture